# Add CCNodes to a Parent CCNode using a for loop

Tags: for-loop, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, sigabrt, ccnode

```
-(CCNode *)createFieldNode:(NSMutableArray *)fieldArray{

    CGSize winSize = [CCDirector sharedDirector].viewSize;
    CCNode* stackNode= [CCNode node];

    for (int i; i <=fieldArray.count; i++){
        //itemP is previous item in array and itemC is current item in area based on index i 
        BPItem*itemP;
        BPItem*itemC;

        if(i!=0){
            itemP=[fieldArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
            itemC=[fieldArray objectAtIndex:i];
            float stackWidth=arc4random()%200+50; 
            float stackHeight=itemP.position.y+itemP.contentSize.height;
            itemC.position=ccp(stackWidth,stackHeight);
        }
        else{
            itemC=[fieldArray objectAtIndex:i];
            float stackWidth=arc4random()%200+50; 
            itemC.position=ccp(stackWidth,0);
        }

        //having trouble adding multiple nodes to stackNode
        [stackNode addChild:itemC];
    }

    return stackNode; 
}
```

I want to add CCNodes from fieldArray on to a parent CCNode "stackNode". When I use breakpoints I am able to add the CCNode at index 0 and CCNode at index 1. However the program crash at i=2. The error I receive is:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'child already added to another node. It can't be added again'

Before the crash "stackNode" has two children. I'm not adding the CCNodes one by one because I have hundreds of different arrays with many a fieldArray.count around 20. Please help I can explain more if I have been unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the for loop start as follows :

```
//itemP is previous item in array and itemC is current item in area based on index i 
BPItem*itemP;
BPItem*itemC;                             // moved out of the for loop
for (int i; i <fieldArray.count; i++){    // <- changed the end condition to avoid crash
   ... rest of loop
```

Also, in the code that creates fieldArray, make certain you have logic to ensure that there are no duplicates, otherwise you will have the same issue (but for an altogether different reason).